# Sonarqube SonarQube server can not be reached works with IP address but not FQDN

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I deployed a sonarqube server on kubernetes with an ingress for access in https and integrated sonarqube with my local gitlab.

When my pipeline is executed I get `[ERROR] SonarQube server [https://sonarqube.mydomain.com] can not be reached` but when I change to IP without https and target port 9000 it works fine

I set the Server base URL to the right value but I don't know why using FQDN doesn't work, did anyone managed to solve the issue ?

here some details about my installation

I installed sonarqube with helm

```
helm upgrade --install -n sonarqube sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube -f values.yaml
```

configured ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 kind: Ingress metadata:   annotations:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: sonarqube
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: sonarqube
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64m   labels:
    app: sonarqube
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: sonarqube-10.1.0_628
    heritage: Helm
    release: sonarqube   name: sonarqube-sonarqube   namespace: sonarqube spec:   ingressClassName: nginx   rules:
  - host: sonarqube.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: sonarqube-sonarqube
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific   tls:
  - hosts:
    - sonarqube.mydomain.com
    secretName: sonar-tls


kubectl -n sonarqube get all

NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/sonarqube-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          23h
pod/sonarqube-sonarqube-0    1/1     Running   0          23h

    NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
    service/sonarqube-postgresql            ClusterIP      10.104.77.155   <none>        5432/TCP         23h
    service/sonarqube-postgresql-headless   ClusterIP      None            <none>        5432/TCP         23h
    service/sonarqube-sonarqube             LoadBalancer   10.97.71.8      10.10.10.33    9000:31092/TCP   23h
    
    NAME                                    READY   AGE
    statefulset.apps/sonarqube-postgresql   1/1     23h
    statefulset.apps/sonarqube-sonarqube    1/1     23h
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this might be the IP that's added to the security group which does not have the required port for connection. For specific GitHub actions IP check by updating the workflow to temporary all open ports.
Error can also be from some proxy set up between nodes, where the scanner is the SonarQube. Check the proxies configuration and certificates, sonarqube site might be using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097414) if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the domain name I tried with the address IP and it works I exposed my sonarqube service as a LoadBalancer service on port 9000 and it works fine.

Using FQDN with ingress with an SSL certificate or without SSL certificate http protocole doesn't work and I have the error message mentioned before.

I tried the same thing with a docker image on another server and exactly the same problem IP works but FQDN with nginx reverse proxy doesn't work and I get error "server cannot be reached" it's not really a matter of IP authorization here